# Where can I find data on when each country first implemented social restrictions for COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, reference-request, data-sources

Regarding COVID-19 response, we have [the stringency index](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/covid-stringency-index). But I wonder, is there any source that **documented the first law implementation date or month regarding societal restrictions** (social distancing, school closures, workplace closures, and travel bans) in each country?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The data for the stringency index linked in the question comes from the University of Oxford's [Covid-19 Government Response Tracker](https://www.bsg.ox.ac.uk/research/research-projects/covid-19-government-response-tracker). In order to calculate this index, manually collated data on policy decisions is used - these are described in their GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/blob/master/documentation/codebook.md), and fall into a number of categories:

- C - containment and closure policies
- E - economic policies
- H - health system policies
- V - vaccination policies
- M - miscellaneous policies

Timeseries data on the implementation of these policies can be found [here](https://github.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/tree/master/data/timeseries). Focusing in particular on the '[C - containment and closure policies](https://github.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/blob/master/documentation/codebook.md#containment-and-closure-policies)', as I think these most closely reflect the social restriction policies you describe, we can identify which countries/areas are recorded as implementing these policies first. For example, looking at table `C1_School closing`, the first area reported as implementing school closures is Macao on  January 24th. With a bit of googling, we can see that this correlates to [this press release](https://www.gov.mo/en/news/122283/).

The 'C-category' policies are:

1. Closings of schools and universities
2. Closings of workplaces
3. Cancelling public events
4. Limits on gatherings
5. Closing of public transport
6. Orders to "shelter-in-place" and otherwise confine to the home
7. Restrictions on internal movement between cities/regions
8. Restrictions on international travel

If we wanted to look at the date of first implementation of any of these C-category policies by country, we can sum up these tables and look at the first date column which records a non-zero number for each country. This gives the below data. For some reason, there is no data recorded for Comoros.

```
| Country                      | Date of first implementation of social restrictions |
| ---------------------------- | --------------------------------------------------- |
| Singapore                    | 01/01/2020                                          |
| Hong Kong                    | 01/01/2020                                          |
| Taiwan                       | 01/01/2020                                          |
| Macao                        | 06/01/2020                                          |
| Japan                        | 07/01/2020                                          |
| Turkmenistan                 | 08/01/2020                                          |
| Bhutan                       | 15/01/2020                                          |
| Guyana                       | 18/01/2020                                          |
| Indonesia                    | 18/01/2020                                          |
| Kenya                        | 20/01/2020                                          |
| Uganda                       | 20/01/2020                                          |
| Guatemala                    | 21/01/2020                                          |
| France                       | 22/01/2020                                          |
| China                        | 22/01/2020                                          |
| Serbia                       | 22/01/2020                                          |
| Canada                       | 22/01/2020                                          |
| Panama                       | 22/01/2020                                          |
| Kyrgyz Republic              | 22/01/2020                                          |
| Bangladesh                   | 22/01/2020                                          |
| United Arab Emirates         | 23/01/2020                                          |
| South Africa                 | 23/01/2020                                          |
| Italy                        | 23/01/2020                                          |
| Qatar                        | 24/01/2020                                          |
| Ghana                        | 24/01/2020                                          |
| Turkey                       | 24/01/2020                                          |
| Monaco                       | 24/01/2020                                          |
| Nepal                        | 25/01/2020                                          |
| Vietnam                      | 25/01/2020                                          |
| India                        | 26/01/2020                                          |
| Barbados                     | 26/01/2020                                          |
| Sri Lanka                    | 26/01/2020                                          |
| Rwanda                       | 27/01/2020                                          |
| Czech Republic               | 27/01/2020                                          |
| Romania                      | 27/01/2020                                          |
| Mongolia                     | 27/01/2020                                          |
| Papua New Guinea             | 27/01/2020                                          |
| Bahrain                      | 27/01/2020                                          |
| Tonga                        | 27/01/2020                                          |
| Georgia                      | 28/01/2020                                          |
| Ethiopia                     | 28/01/2020                                          |
| Botswana                     | 28/01/2020                                          |
| Zimbabwe                     | 28/01/2020                                          |
| Kazakhstan                   | 29/01/2020                                          |
| Iceland                      | 29/01/2020                                          |
| Eswatini                     | 29/01/2020                                          |
| Russia                       | 30/01/2020                                          |
| Azerbaijan                   | 30/01/2020                                          |
| Brunei                       | 30/01/2020                                          |
| Trinidad and Tobago          | 30/01/2020                                          |
| Tanzania                     | 30/01/2020                                          |
| Puerto Rico                  | 30/01/2020                                          |
| Malaysia                     | 30/01/2020                                          |
| El Salvador                  | 31/01/2020                                          |
| Jamaica                      | 31/01/2020                                          |
| South Korea                  | 31/01/2020                                          |
| Philippines                  | 31/01/2020                                          |
| Pakistan                     | 31/01/2020                                          |
| Syria                        | 01/02/2020                                          |
| Benin                        | 01/02/2020                                          |
| Kiribati                     | 01/02/2020                                          |
| Australia                    | 01/02/2020                                          |
| Myanmar                      | 01/02/2020                                          |
| Belize                       | 02/02/2020                                          |
| United States                | 02/02/2020                                          |
| New Zealand                  | 02/02/2020                                          |
| Israel                       | 02/02/2020                                          |
| Timor-Leste                  | 03/02/2020                                          |
| Bulgaria                     | 03/02/2020                                          |
| Oman                         | 03/02/2020                                          |
| Tajikistan                   | 03/02/2020                                          |
| Fiji                         | 03/02/2020                                          |
| Haiti                        | 04/02/2020                                          |
| Croatia                      | 04/02/2020                                          |
| Mauritania                   | 05/02/2020                                          |
| Angola                       | 06/02/2020                                          |
| Solomon Islands              | 06/02/2020                                          |
| Finland                      | 06/02/2020                                          |
| Gabon                        | 07/02/2020                                          |
| Bermuda                      | 07/02/2020                                          |
| Seychelles                   | 07/02/2020                                          |
| Lebanon                      | 08/02/2020                                          |
| Libya                        | 10/02/2020                                          |
| Mozambique                   | 11/02/2020                                          |
| Iran                         | 20/02/2020                                          |
| Iraq                         | 20/02/2020                                          |
| Democratic Republic of Congo | 20/02/2020                                          |
| Nicaragua                    | 21/02/2020                                          |
| Zambia                       | 21/02/2020                                          |
| Kuwait                       | 21/02/2020                                          |
| Cuba                         | 21/02/2020                                          |
| Afghanistan                  | 23/02/2020                                          |
| Malta                        | 23/02/2020                                          |
| San Marino                   | 23/02/2020                                          |
| Colombia                     | 24/02/2020                                          |
| South Sudan                  | 24/02/2020                                          |
| Switzerland                  | 25/02/2020                                          |
| Albania                      | 25/02/2020                                          |
| Germany                      | 26/02/2020                                          |
| Moldova                      | 26/02/2020                                          |
| Latvia                       | 27/02/2020                                          |
| Cape Verde                   | 27/02/2020                                          |
| Liechtenstein                | 28/02/2020                                          |
| Mexico                       | 28/02/2020                                          |
| Greece                       | 29/02/2020                                          |
| Namibia                      | 01/03/2020                                          |
| Vanuatu                      | 01/03/2020                                          |
| Uzbekistan                   | 01/03/2020                                          |
| Ecuador                      | 02/03/2020                                          |
| Sweden                       | 02/03/2020                                          |
| Congo                        | 03/03/2020                                          |
| Denmark                      | 03/03/2020                                          |
| Faeroe Islands               | 04/03/2020                                          |
| Belgium                      | 04/03/2020                                          |
| Tunisia                      | 04/03/2020                                          |
| Palestine                    | 05/03/2020                                          |
| Burundi                      | 05/03/2020                                          |
| Thailand                     | 06/03/2020                                          |
| Lesotho                      | 06/03/2020                                          |
| Peru                         | 06/03/2020                                          |
| Slovak Republic              | 06/03/2020                                          |
| Slovenia                     | 07/03/2020                                          |
| Cambodia                     | 07/03/2020                                          |
| Guinea                       | 07/03/2020                                          |
| Chad                         | 08/03/2020                                          |
| Saudi Arabia                 | 08/03/2020                                          |
| Luxembourg                   | 09/03/2020                                          |
| Hungary                      | 09/03/2020                                          |
| Austria                      | 09/03/2020                                          |
| Spain                        | 09/03/2020                                          |
| Poland                       | 09/03/2020                                          |
| Portugal                     | 09/03/2020                                          |
| Bosnia and Herzegovina       | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Liberia                      | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Costa Rica                   | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Paraguay                     | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Netherlands                  | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Algeria                      | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Norway                       | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Cyprus                       | 10/03/2020                                          |
| Mali                         | 11/03/2020                                          |
| Argentina                    | 11/03/2020                                          |
| Kosovo                       | 11/03/2020                                          |
| Eritrea                      | 11/03/2020                                          |
| Laos                         | 11/03/2020                                          |
| Venezuela                    | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Burkina Faso                 | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Ireland                      | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Bolivia                      | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Lithuania                    | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Ukraine                      | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Brazil                       | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Estonia                      | 12/03/2020                                          |
| Honduras                     | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Greenland                    | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Andorra                      | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Uruguay                      | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Suriname                     | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Morocco                      | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Niger                        | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Cameroon                     | 13/03/2020                                          |
| United Kingdom               | 13/03/2020                                          |
| Somalia                      | 14/03/2020                                          |
| Belarus                      | 14/03/2020                                          |
| Sudan                        | 14/03/2020                                          |
| Senegal                      | 14/03/2020                                          |
| Yemen                        | 15/03/2020                                          |
| Egypt                        | 15/03/2020                                          |
| Madagascar                   | 15/03/2020                                          |
| Chile                        | 15/03/2020                                          |
| Jordan                       | 15/03/2020                                          |
| Dominican Republic           | 16/03/2020                                          |
| Guam                         | 16/03/2020                                          |
| Sierra Leone                 | 16/03/2020                                          |
| Bahamas                      | 16/03/2020                                          |
| Cote d'Ivoire                | 16/03/2020                                          |
| Togo                         | 16/03/2020                                          |
| Aruba                        | 16/03/2020                                          |
| Mauritius                    | 18/03/2020                                          |
| Djibouti                     | 18/03/2020                                          |
| United States Virgin Islands | 18/03/2020                                          |
| Nigeria                      | 18/03/2020                                          |
| Gambia                       | 18/03/2020                                          |
| Malawi                       | 20/03/2020                                          |
| Dominica                     | 22/03/2020                                          |
| Central African Republic     | 26/03/2020                                          |
```